# How to display title text(in the nav bar) above TabGroup in Android in Titanium?

Tags: android, titanium

Does any one know how to display title text(in the nav bar) above TabGroup in Android in Titanium?

I know I can set title to display at each tab, but how about the one on top of the tab group?

It only has an application icon at left and rather strange there if it's android. I tried to set navBarHidden : true so that nav bar won't show, but the icon inside tab also goes hidden...

Please kindly advise me here...thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set title/icon and handle icon click events of the action bar with the following code

```
    // Set activity title and back functionality
    if( Ti.Platform.Android.API_LEVEL >= 11 ) {
        var activity = tabGroup.getActivity();
        activity.actionBar.icon = "/images/icon.png";
        activity.actionBar.title = "Title";
        activity.actionBar.onHomeIconItemSelected = function() {
            doSomething();
        };
     }
```

This example assumes that your tab group is called tabGroup. You could also do this with a window activity `var activity = win.getActivity();`

You can find more on this topic in the [Titanium docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Android.ActionBar).